# SQL query of a string (nvarcahr(256)) doesn't give the data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, nvarchar, data-connections

[Table design]:

[image]

I inserted to the table using:

```
INSERT INTO Orders 
VALUES (N'Test', 10, 20)
```

[Data in the table]:

[image]

Now when I try to set a query to get row in the table by user name.

So I used the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE User = N'Test'
```

Trying to get the row by User:

[image]

But I get zero results from the query although the table have a row with the User "Test".

For testing I tried to do the same thing but search by the `ItemId` or `ItemAmount` and it returns results.

[Searching by int returns result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRK5.jpg)

I am new about using SQL Server `.mdf` database files. But not with .db and SQL query.

So how can I fix the problem or get the unique User row, without adding another col to the table?

Comment: @YogeshSharma Thank's it worked!!!

Comment: This is one reason why one should avoid using [reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) as identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape column name with `[]`:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE [User] = N'Test';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e69f4c35467507695340281356a0c01)**

In SQL Server `User` <> `[User]`:

```
SELECT User, [User]
FROM Orders;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63012af548f3d0436cab443307b84b10)**